# HTML: Display a string from a separate PHP file

Tags: php, html, string

I've searched all over the internet and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I want to be able to "call" a php file from an html file and display the string returned:

html_ONLY_file.html

```
...
<h1>GetHeader.php?type=main</h1>
...
```

GetHeader.php

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'main')
   print 'Some header to display'; //or echo 'Some...';

exit;
```

I've done this for images, img src="image.php?file=file.jpg", where image.php does a header(...) and readfile(...) return but I do not know how to do this for simple text. I'm not looking for DOM or anything too involved, if I have to I will. I want to know if there is a simple solution. It's generating the html side that I'm lost on.

In case you want to know, I am doing this because I once used a <#virtual include=...> to call for a php file from my .shtml file. Well, the hosting company decided to change mod_security and now I cannot include any php files (I've already tried everything). Including html files works fine and so I am changing this part of the website around so I don't have to rename files because the site is for a small business that is now ranked highly on Google for its geographical area. If I change the file names, shtml to php, then I believe the Google ranking drops (don't comment on this part unless you are damn sure you are 100% correct).

Comment: I don't think you CAN do this.

Comment: HTML can't do this. You can do it with Javascript AJAX.

Comment: You can't do this. You can however do this vice versa. For example, you have a file index.php, you can `include('file.html');`

Comment: PHP delimiters can only be recognized inside files with extension '.php', except in Apache, where you would have to add '.html'  as Apache Handler for PHP- (not recommended).

Comment: Can you edit your .htaccess file?

Comment: I think the only way to fix the issue is just rename every page on the site to .php.

Comment: .htaccess seemed to disappear after the upgrade. The company said they disabled mod_security and everything should be fine now...which it isn't because they didn't check.

Comment: I would double check because that's something you should definitely have access to. If you don't, that company doesn't know what they're doing. I'll go ahead and post my answer (which assumes you have access to the htaccess file) because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the `.htaccess` file you can add a line in your `.htaccess` file that will mean HTML files will be parsed as if they were PHP.

**If your server is running PHP as an apache module:**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

**If your server is running PHP as CGI:**

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

*Source: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/php-in-html-files.html*

Once you've added that your `html_ONLY_file.html` could look like:

```
<h1><?php print "some header"; ?></h1>
```

And it would function just as if it were a `.php` file.

---

Alternatively, you could convert all your files to `.php` and add redirects into the `.htaccess` file like so:

```
rewriteRule ^somefile.shtml$ somefile.php [R=301,L]
rewriteRule ^another-file.shtml$ another-file.php [R=301,L]
```

This effectively says to your server "whenever a user requests `somefile.shtml`, act as if they requested `somefile.php` instead". The `R=301` is the **most important part** with regards to Google rankings. This tells Google (and anyone who requests the `.shtml` file) that it's **permanently moved** to the new location `somefile.php`. This transfers all / almost all of the ranking power from the old location to the new location.

*Source: http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection*